# Can $x= x_0$ in the process of $x \to x_0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

In the process of  $               x→x_0          $,can $x$ get the value of $x_0$ ? i.e. can $x= x_0$ here ?

Comment: No. $x$ is close enough $x_0$ but $x\ne x_0$.

Comment: @Cao In $\lim_{{\Delta{x}\to{0}}}\Delta{y}={0}$,

 it is another definition of function continuity ,can Δx get the value of 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a concrete example, consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\neq 0\\500&x=0\end{cases}.$$

In this case, what is $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$? Ignoring the Cauchy epsilon-delta argument for now, we note that as long as $x\neq 0$, then $f(x)=x^2$. So for $x\approx 0$ but $x\neq 0$, $f(x)$ will continue to approach $0$ and not $500$. Hence the limit should be $0$, but not $500$. In fact, even if $f(x)$ was undefined at $x=0$, the limit would still exist and equal 0.

*Limits are about the journey, not the destination.*

Comment: In $\lim_{{\Delta{x}\to{0}}}\Delta{y}={0}$,

 it is another definition of function continuity ,can Δx get the value of 0 ?

Comment: @iMath $\Delta x$ does not necessarily have to attain the value $0$ in order for the limit to be defined. It merely has to attain values arbitrarily close, but distinct from, $0$.

Comment: yes, what you said is the true meaning of  Δx→0 ,thanks!